# PDOException doesn't fire on statement execution failure

Tags: php, pdo

I'm dabbling with PHP in Google App Engine (and learning about database design and PDO at the same time). Here's a bit of data insertion code which isn't working:

```
<html>
<body>
Collection Protocol
<?php

$db = null;

  try{
     $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/myidhere:cloudsql;dbname=mydb-schema', 'root', '');
  }catch(PDOException $ex){
      die(json_encode(
          array('outcome' => false, 'message' => $ex->getMessage())
          )
      );
  }



try {

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO observations(observation_remote_id_fk, observation_dimension_id_fk, metric) VALUES (:remote_id, :dimension_id, :metric)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':remote_id' => htmlspecialchars('1'), ':dimension_id' => htmlspecialchars('1'), ':metric' => htmlspecialchars('1')));

} catch (PDOException $ex2) {
      die(json_encode(
          array('outcome' => false, 'message' => $ex2->getMessage())
          )
      );


}
$db = null;
?>
</body></html>
```

In my attempts to debug this I've realized my error reporting is not WAI - if I change the database name, I get an error which is great (and expected). But if I change the table name - for example, to something made up that doesn't exist - I don't seem to get a PDOException, which I would have expected. Current theory is the database is connecting okay (it throws an error if it doesn't) but the table bit is broken and not throwing an error.

How can I make PDO fire an exception whenever it can't execute a statement?

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO will throw exceptions if it can't create the object because that's OOP code, but by default it fails silently for mySQL errors, instead passing `false` for the various function returns.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Change your code to set the relevant attribute:

```
$db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/myidhere:cloudsql;dbname=mydb-schema', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks. Error (hadn't populated my foreign keys in the other tables) was immediately obvious and easily solved once it was a little more verbose.

Thanks for being nice about it - realise this is very obvious in the manual, it's just hard to find the right place sometimes when you're just starting out.